# What makes Video Library and picture Library different from Asset Library

Tags: list, picture-library, asset-library, office-365-video-portal

It sounds basic stuff, But need some solid understanding on this. Also can we convert an Asset library to Picture library. After all all of these three asre derived from Generic List only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are the few differences between Picture Library and Asset Library.

- A Picture library can only contain Pictures and not Video and Audio files.An Asset library can contain all of these.
- Picture library have slideshow view of pictures
- Also, when you move your pointer over an asset in the Thumbnails view, a preview window displays a larger version of the image, as well as image properties. You can take actions on the asset from the preview window. This isn't the case with Picture Libraries.
- The Picture Library does NOT allow Edit in Datasheet View; the Asset Library does.

Reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1272cf0c-095f-40d5-bde1-49f1fff70ba1/asset-library-vs-picture-library-which-one-to-use?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious
http://www.sharepointblog.com/2010/07/picture-library-vs-asset-library.html

Comment: Well this really helpful for me.